# Highlight values in Multi-select List

Tags: php, html

I have a form which has a multi-select list field with 3 values and some other fields. I want to highlight selected values from list after submit button using php code. How will I achieve this task?

PHP Code:-

```
<select id="txtconfort" name="txtconfort[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:72%; height:60px;">
    <option value="Power Steering">Power Steering</option>
    <option value="Power Windows">Power Windows</option>
    <option value="Engine Start/Stop Button">Engine Start/Stop Button</option>
</select>
```

For eg. if I select Power Steering and Power Windows then after submit I want to highlight those values in same files using selected property. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<select id="txtconfort" name="txtconfort[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:72%; height:60px;">
    <option value="Power Steering" <?php if(in_array('Power Steering',$_POST['txtconfort'])) { echo "style='background-coloe:#ccc;'" } ?> >Power Steering</option>
    <option value="Power Windows" <?php if(in_array('Power Windows',$_POST['txtconfort'])) { echo "style='background-coloe:#ccc;'" } ?> >Power Windows</option>
    <option value="Engine Start/Stop Button" <?php if(in_array('Engine Start/Stop Button',$_POST['txtconfort'])) { echo "style='background-coloe:#ccc;'" } ?> >Engine Start/Stop Button</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can do:

```
<?php 
    $posted_txtconfort = array();
    if(isset($_POST["usubmit"])){
        if(isset($_POST["txtconfort"])) $posted_txtconfort = $_POST["txtconfort"];
    }
?>

<form method="post">
    <select id="txtconfort" name="txtconfort[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:72%; height:60px;">
        <option value="Power Steering" <?php if(sizeof($posted_txtconfort) && in_array("Power Steering",$posted_txtconfort)){ echo "SELECTED" ;}?>>Power Steering</option>
        <option value="Power Windows" <?php if(sizeof($posted_txtconfort) && in_array("Power Windows",$posted_txtconfort)){ echo "SELECTED" ;}?> >Power Windows</option>
        <option value="Engine Start/Stop Button" <?php if(sizeof($posted_txtconfort) && in_array("Engine Start/Stop Button",$posted_txtconfort)){ echo "SELECTED" ;}?> >Engine Start/Stop Button</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="usubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The above code will make sure that you do not receive any undefined index when you do not post the data.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
<select id="txtconfort" name="txtconfort[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:72%; height:60px;">
    <option value="Power Steering" <?php if(in_array('Power Steering',$_POST['txtconfort'])) { echo "selected='true'" } ?> >Power Steering</option>
    <option value="Power Windows" <?php if(in_array('Power Windows',$_POST['txtconfort'])) { echo "selected='true'" } ?> >Power Windows</option>
    <option value="Engine Start/Stop Button" <?php if(in_array('Engine Start/Stop Button',$_POST['txtconfort'])) { echo "selected='true'" } ?> >Engine Start/Stop Button</option>
</select>
```

> Logic is to `echo` `selected="true"` for every option if it is present in the array
>
> You may use this in loop also to render the option statements